# Examples of histomorphisms in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I recently read [1] and [2], which speak about histomorphism (and dynamorphisms) which are recursion schemes that can express e.g. dynamic programming. Unfortunately the papers aren't accessible if you don't know category theory, even though there's code in there that looks like Haskell.

Could someone explain histomorphisms with an example that uses real Haskell code?

1. [Histo- and Dynamorphisms Revisited](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/nicolas.wu/publications/Histomorphisms.pdf)
2. [Recursion Schemes for Dynamic Programming](http://math.ut.ee/~eugene/kabanov-vene-mpc-06.pdf)

Comment: Have you seen [pointless-haskell](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointless-haskell-0.0.8)? It has examples for both histomorphisms and dynamorphisms, although the only example for a histomorphism is the Fibonacci sequence. Maybe someone can use those examples to explain the -morphisms.

Comment: @Zeta I have, but it communicates the ideas about as clearly as the papers: `histo :: (Mu a,Functor (PF a)) => Ann a -> (F a (Histo a c) -> c) -> a -> c`

Comment: `recursion-schemes` has `histo` and `dyna` is just `histo` that works on any coalgebra, not just final ones. The most trivial interesting example I can think of is a rather direct `tail` built off a generalized `foldr :: (a -> b -> b -> b) -> (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's start by defining a data type that we will use as an example:

```
data Nat = S Nat | Z
```

This data type encodes the natural numbers in Peano style. This means that we have 0 and a way to produce the successor of any natural number.

We can construct new natural numbers from integers easily:

```
-- Allow us to construct Nats
mkNat :: Integer -> Nat
mkNat n | n < 0 = error "cannot construct negative natural number"
mkNat 0 = Z
mkNat n = S $ mkNat (n-1)
```

Now, we'll first define a catamorphism for this type, because a histomorphism is quite similar to it and a catamorphism is easier to understand.

A catamorphism allows to "fold" or "tear down" a structure. It only expects a function that knows how to fold the structure *when all recursive terms* have been folded already. Let's define such a type, similar to Nat, but with all recursive instances replaced by some value of type `a`:

```
data NatF a = SF a | ZF -- Aside: this is just Maybe
```

Now, we can define the type of our catamorphism for Nat:

```
cata :: (NatF a -> a)
     -> (Nat -> a)
```

Given a function that knows how to fold the non-recursive structure `NatF a` to an `a`, `cata` turns that into a function to fold a whole `Nat`.

The implementation of cata is quite simple: first fold the recursive subterm (if there is any) and the apply our function:

```
cata f Z = f ZF -- No subterm to fold, base case
cata f (S subterm) = f $ SF $ cata f subterm -- Fold subterm first, recursive case
```

We can use this catamorphism to convert `Nat`s back to `Integer`s, like this:

```
natToInteger :: Nat -> Integer
natToInteger = cata phi where
  -- We only need to provide a function to fold
  -- a non-recursive Nat-like structure
  phi :: NatF Integer -> Integer
  phi ZF = 0
  phi (SF x) = x + 1
```

So with `cata`, we get access to the value of the immediate subterm. But imagine we like to access the values of transitive subterms too, for example, when defining a fibonacci function. Then, we need not only access to the previous value, but also to the 2-nd previous value. This is where histomorphisms come into play.

A histomorphism (histo sounds a lot like "history") allows us to access *all* previous values, not just the most recent one. This means we now get a list of values, not just a single one, so the type of histomorphism is:

```
-- We could use the type NatF (NonEmptyList a) here.
-- But because NatF is Maybe, NatF (NonEmptyList a) is equal to [a].
-- Using just [a] is a lot simpler
histo :: ([a] -> a)
      -> Nat -> a
histo f = head . go where
  -- go :: Nat -> [a]  -- This signature would need ScopedTVs
  go Z = [f []]
  go (S x) = let subvalues = go x in f subvalues : subvalues
```

Now, we can define `fibN` as follows:

```
-- Example: calculate the n-th fibonacci number
fibN :: Nat -> Integer
fibN = histo $ \x -> case x of
 (x:y:_) -> x + y
 _       -> 1
```

Aside: even though it might appear so, histo is not more powerful than cata. You can see that yourself by implementing histo in terms of cata and the other way around.

---

What I didn't show in the above example is that `cata` and `histo` can be implemented very generally if you define your type as a fixpoint of a functor. Our `Nat` type is just the fixed point of the Functor `NatF`.

If you define `histo` in the generic way, then you also need to come up with a type like the `NonEmptyList` in our example, but for any functor. This type is precisely `Cofree f`, where `f` is the functor you took the fixed point of. You can see that it works for our example: `NonEmptyList` is just `Cofree Maybe`. This is how you get to the generic type of `histo`:

```
histo :: Functor f 
      => (f (Cofree f a) -> a)
      -> Fix f  -- ^ This is the fixed point of f
      -> a
```

You can think of `f (Cofree f a)` as kind of a stack, where with each "layer", you can see a less-folded structure. At the top of the stack, every immediate subterm is folded. Then, if you go one layer deeper, the immediate subterm is no longer folded, but the sub-subterms are all already folded (or evaluated, which might make more sense to say in the case of ASTs). So you can basically see "the sequence of reductions" that has been applied (= the history).

Comment: cata-, histo-, ana-, apo-, and hylomorphisms are implemented in the [recursion-schemes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) package.  The documentation is lacking, but by either defining your functor as a fixed point (Mu type, Nu type, or direct) or providing a Base functor and project/embed you get an instance of Foldable/Unfoldable with many of the morphisms you desire.

Comment: Then you can get the `dyna`morphism by just being less strict about the choice of coalgebra: `dyna :: Functor f => (f (Cofree f a) -> a) -> (c -> f c) -> (c -> a)`. Here `c` replaces `Fix f` and `(c -> f c)` is a less restrictive form of `recursion-schemes`' [`project`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:cata)

Comment: I wasn't expecting `cata` and `histo` to be equally powerful. Is `dyna` then more powerful?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson isn't `dyna` just passing the `Foldable` dictionary manually? so dyna is to histo as sortBy is to sort ?

Comment: @tibbe My suspicion is that histo and cata aren't equally powerful in weaker/larger categorical settings. I haven't tried implementing `histo` using `cata`, but I have a suspicion that it requires [`strength`](http://comonad.com/reader/2008/deriving-strength-from-laziness/).

Comment: @bennofs That's how I think of it, along with the restriction that what you pass to `sortBy` ought to "make sense"; you can't just pass any old coalgebra to `dyna`. The only difference is that there's in some sense, in Haskell, a *proper* coalgebra for any algebraic data type which is what `Foldable` captures.

Answer (score 13):

We can think of there as being a generalization continuum from `cata` to `histo` to `dyna`. In the terminology of `recursion-schemes`:

```
Foldable t => (Base t a -> a)                                  -> (t -> a) -- (1)
Foldable t => (Base t (Cofree (Base t) a) -> a)                -> (t -> a) -- (2)
Functor  f => (f      (Cofree f        a) -> a) ->  (t -> f t) -> (t -> a) -- (3)
```

where (1) is `cata`, (2) is `histo`, and (3) is `dyna`. A high-level overview of this generalization is that `histo` improves `cata` by maintaing the history of all partial "right folds" and `dyna` improves `histo` by letting operating on any type `t` so long as we can make an `f`-coalgebra for it, not just the `Foldable` ones (which have universal `Base t`-coalgebras as `Foldable` witnesses that data types are final coalgebras).

We can almost read off their properties by simply looking at what it takes to fulfill their types.

For instance, a classic use of `cata` is to define `foldr`

```
data instance Prim [a] x = Nil | Cons a x
type instance Base [a] = Prim [a]

instance Foldable [a] where
  project []     = Nil
  project (a:as) = Cons a as

foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr cons nil = cata $ \case
  Nil      -> nil
  Cons a b -> cons a b
```

importantly, we note that `foldr` generates the "next" partial right fold value by using exclusively the "previous" right fold value. This is why it can be implemented using `cata`: it only needs the most immediately previous partial fold result.

As `histo` generalizes `cata` we ought to be able to do the same with it. Here's a `histo`-based `foldr`

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr cons nil = histo $ \case
  Nil             -> nil
  Cons a (b :< _) -> cons a b
```

we can see that we no longer *immediately* have the immediately previous fold result, but instead have to reach into the first layer of the `Cofree` in order to find it. But `Cofree` is a stream and contains potentially infinitely many "previous fold values" and we can dig as deeply into it as we like. This is what gives `histo` its "historical" power. For instance, we can write a fairly direct `tail` using `histo` which is more difficult to do with `cata` alone:

```
tail :: [a] -> Maybe [a]
tail = histo $ \case
  Nil             -> Nothing -- empty list
  Cons _ (b :< x) -> case x of
    Nil       -> Just [] -- length 1 list
    Cons a _ -> fmap (a:) b
```

The style is a little indirect, but essentially because we can look back into the past *two* steps we can respond to length-1 lists differently from length-0 lists or length-`n` lists.

To take the final step to generalize `histo` to `dyna` we simply replace the natural projection by *any* coalgebra. We could thus implement `histo` in terms of `dyna` quite easily

```
histo phi = dyna phi project -- project is from the Foldable class
```

So now we can apply `histo` folds to any type which can even be partially viewed as a list (well, so long as we keep with the running example and use `Prim [a]` as the `Functor`, `f`).

> (Theoretically, there's a restriction that this coalgebra eventually *halts*, e.g. we can't treat infinite streams, but that has more to do with theory and optimization than use. In use, such a thing simply has to be lazy and small enough to terminate.)
>
> (This mirrors the idea of representing initial algebras by their ability to `project :: t -> Base t t`. If this were truly a total inductive type then you could only project so many times before hitting the end.)

To replicate the Catalan numbers instance from the linked paper we can create non-empty lists

```
data NEL  a   = Some  a | More  a (NEL a)
data NELf a x = Somef a | Moref a x deriving Functor
```

and create the coalgebra on natural numbers called `natural` which, suitably unfolded, produces a countdown `NEL`

```
natural :: Int -> NELf Int Int
natural 0 = Somef 0
natural n = Moref n (n-1)
```

then we apply a `histo`-style fold to the `NELf`-view of a natural number to produce the `n`-th Catalan number.

```
-- here's a quick implementation of `dyna` using `recursion-schemes`

zcata
  :: (Comonad w, Functor f) =>
     (a -> f a) -> (f (w (w c)) -> w b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
zcata z k g = g . extract . c where
  c = k . fmap (duplicate . fmap g . c) . z

dyna :: Functor f => (f (Cofree f c) -> c) -> (a -> f a) -> a -> c
dyna phi z = zcata z distHisto phi

takeC :: Int -> Cofree (NELf a) a -> [a]
takeC 0 _                 = []
takeC n (a :< Somef v)    = [a]
takeC n (a :< Moref v as) = a : takeC (n-1) as

catalan :: Int -> Int
catalan = dyna phi natural where
  phi :: NELf Int (Cofree (NELf Int) Int) -> Int
  phi (Somef 0) = 1
  phi (Moref n table) = sum (zipWith (*) xs (reverse xs))
    where xs = takeC n table
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `Base` and `Prim`. I see that they're defined in recursion-schemes, but the module they're defined in lacks any docs. Why does recursion-schemes define a different `Foldable` class than the commonly used one? What does the `project` function in that class do?

Comment: `Base` is a type family where `Base t` is the signature functor of the type `t`, i.e. the `f` in the `f`-algebra that `t` is the final/initial co/alebgra of. `Foldable` here is a generalized form of `Data.Foldable`—you can see `Data.Foldable` as `Data.Functor.Foldable` specialized such that `Base (t a) = Base [a]`. Finally, `project` is basically `uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a, [a])` but, again, generalized to arbitrary `Base` functors.

Comment: Oh! And since `Base` is just a type family, `Prim` is a data family which lets you avoid going around making new names for data types like `ListSignature`, `MaybeSignature`, `BoolSignature`, `NatSignature`. It's just convenience to have both `Base` and `Prim`.

Comment: What's the point in resorting to dyna for catalan numbers instead of doing it with histo directly?