# Haskell Recursion Schemes: Label the tree with intermediate results

Tags: haskell, recursion, recursive-datastructures, recursion-schemes, corecursion

Using `cata` I can fold an AST to a result. With `Cofree` I can store additional annotations on the AST. How can I take an AST and return an annotated AST with the results at each step of the way?

```
alg :: Term Result -> Result
alg = undefined

run :: Fix Term -> Result
run ast = cata alg ast

run' :: Fix Term -> Cofree Term Result
run' = ???
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38462563/how-to-work-with-ast-with-cofree-annotation

Comment: (tl;dr: use `Product`, not `Cofree`, for labelling.)

Comment: When you use `Product`,  it will iterate on both structures simoultaniasly, correct ?

Comment: Have a look at the linked answer. If the other half of the functor product contains no `a`s (ie `Const k`) there's nothing to iterate.

Comment: The answer says that this method doesn't allow the algorithm to traverse the tree.

Comment: `hoistFix` doesn't, but you can still use `cata` or `ana`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this modified algebra work?

```
alg' :: Term (Cofree Term Result) -> Cofree Term Result
alg' t = alg (fmap extract t) :< t  

run' :: Fix Term -> Cofree Term Result
run' ast = cata alg' ast
```

[`extract`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/comonad-5/docs/Control-Comonad.html#v:extract) is from `Control.Comonad`. We are using it here with type `Cofree Term Result -> Result`. It simply returns the annotation at the root.

`fmap extract :: Term (Cofree Term Result) -> Term Result` lets us reuse our previous `alg` definition.

Comment: Thanks! But there is another problem: actually my `Result` is wrapped in a monad. So `run' :: Fix Term -> Cofree Term (m Result)`.
What can I do to get `m (Cofree Term Result)` ?

Comment: @user47376 Is your original algebra like `alg :: Term (m Result) -> m Result` ?

Comment: Yes. The full type is `hm :: (MonadError TypeError m,MonadState Count m) => Term (Alias m) -> Alias m`. Where `type Alias m = Enviroment -> m (Substitution,Type)`. So it's actually wrapped in all sorts of things. I'm only interested in `Type`. So the final result should be `Cofree Term Type`

Comment: @user47376 In that case I'm not sure how to reutilize `alg` in the definition of `alg'`. But perhaps you could define `alg'` (the algebra that returns annotated trees) directly and work with it from the start? It's easy to "forget the tree" and just keep the root result, after all.

Comment: @user47376 I've just remember that there exists a recursion scheme called "histomorphism" which comes with the "Cofree annotating all previous results" baked-in. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884475/examples-of-histomorphisms-in-haskell http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html#v:histo I'm still unsure about how to integrate it with returning functions / monadic effects.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a simple catamorphism, you could use a function like [`cataM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-ext-0.2.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable-Exotic.html#v:cataM). This allows you to fold monadic values such that the actions are properly ordered. Plus, you don't need to write any boilerplate to wrap your F-algebra.

Then

```
alg :: Term Result -> Cofree Term Result
alg = undefined

run' :: Fix Term -> Cofree Term Result
run' = cataM alg
```